# where is php.ini on snow leopard on a fresh install

Tags: php

So i have the line in the http.conf that relates to PHP uncommented out and i have mysql installed but where is my php.ini file located for me to point to mysql.sock.

Comment: I don't have my mac handy, just do a spotlight search for "php.ini" It'll tell you.

Comment: `find / -name php.ini` or `locate php.ini`. Generally it's buried somewhere in /etc, either directly in there, or on a PHP-ish subdir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure where yours is... but you can use PHP to tell you where it is.

On a command line, issue `'which php' --ini` (note those apostrophes should be backticks, SO formatting got me).  If you don't have `which` and know your path to PHP, just use `<path to php> --ini`.

Answer (score 2):

Make a file in your webroot and have it contain:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

Then visit the page and it should tell you where it is.

As far as I know, php.ini should be in /etc